# Error en clase R.id

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite, onclick

Me marca error en los case R.id.btn, mi sintaxis esta bien bien pero por algun motivo me marca error y no se porque (dejo imagen del error), estoy usando la version de android studio flamingo

Estoy creando una base de datos en Android Studio con sqlite, me marca un error al momento de enlazar mi activity con los id de los botones esto ocurre en mi sentencia switch en los case:
El error desaparece cuando hay otro error pequeño, pero cuando este es correguido el error vuelve aparecer.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import static com.example.myapplication.R.id.btnBusqueda;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.FileNameMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Context contexto;
    Button btnListar, btnBuscar, btnRegistrar;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnBusqueda:
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Buscar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(contexto, GestionarLibroActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.btnRegistrar:
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Registrar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i2 = new Intent(contexto, GestionarLibroActivity.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                break;
            case R.id.btnListado:
                Toast.makeText(contexto, "Listar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i3 = new Intent(contexto, GestionarLibroActivity.class);
                startActivity(i3);
        }
    }
```

Dejo una imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi XML de la interfaz.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido. El código va como texto. Pero usa el botón de las llaves **{}** para darle formato. El que habías usado es para HTML, CSS y Javascript.

Comment: Hola Chido, recuerda que es importante especificar los errores en tu pregunta, esto para tener una respuesta rápida.

Comment: Sugiero que uses métodos diferentes para cada botón, a menos que varios realicen la misma tarea. De hecho, hacerlo mejorará la legibilidad del código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la unica solucion que encontre fue cambiado por anidados, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (R.id.btnBusqueda){
            Toast.makeText(contexto, "Buscar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(contexto, GestionarLibroActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);}

       if (R.id.btnRegistrar){
            Toast.makeText(contexto, "Registrar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i2 = new Intent(contexto, GestionarLibroActivity.class);
            startActivity(i2);}
        if (R.id.btnListado){
            Toast.makeText(contexto, "Listar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i3 = new Intent(contexto, GestionarLibroActivity.class);
            startActivity(i3);}
```

Comment: 1) No hay anidamiento... por qué dices *"anidados"*? Los if anidados van uno dentro de otro, no en fila :) 2) Si utilizas `else if(...){}` en vez de solo `if` (excepto para el primero, que debe ser un `if` "normal") evitarás comprobar todos los casos, una vez que se ejecute uno dejará de probar si los demás se cumplen.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que estás definiendo en tu layout para cada botón que llame el método `onClick()`,

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Pero esto es incorrecto, ya que en tu clase estás definiendo que implemente `View.OnClickListener` y aquí no necesitas definir en tu layout el atributo `android:onClick="onClick"`.

Elimina también el método `init()`, no es necesario para obtener las referencias de las vistas.

El último punto a corregir, en el `switch` usa la variable, no uses el tipo `View` :

```
//switch(View.getId()){
switch(view.getId()){
```

---

Actualización:

Ya se tenían los cambios necesarios, pero en este caso faltaba asignar los `OnClickListener` a cada botón.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context contexto;
    Button btnListar, btnBuscar, btnRegistrar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnBuscar = findViewById(R.id.btnBusqueda);
        btnListar = findViewById(R.id.btnListado);
        btnRegistrar = findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrar);

        //Define listeners a botones.
        btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnListar.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnBusqueda:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Buscar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GestionarLibroActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.btnRegistrar:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registrar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GestionarLibroActivity.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                break;
            case R.id.btnListado:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Listar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GestionarLibroActivity.class);
                startActivity(i3);
        }
    }
}
```

Si deseas usar el atributo `android:onClick="onClick"` debes eliminar la asignación de los listener y tu programa tendría el mismo funcionamiento.

Comment: debo borrar el onclick de mi xml?, ya lo intente y me sigue marcando error

Comment: si debes eliminarlos de los botones en tu layout activity_main.xml

Comment: ya los elimine y me sigue marcando el mismo error, limpie el proyecto y le di rebuild, pero me sigue marcando lo mismo :c

Comment: especificamente que error es el que muestra

Comment: me sigue saliendo el error de Constant expression required

Comment: ya veo!, además de lo que comenté . elimina el método init() este ya no es necesario, prueba nuevamente.

Comment: Ya elimine el metodo, limpie proyecto e hice rebuild, pero aun me sigue marcando el mismo error :c

Comment: @ElChido el último punto a cambiar revisalo en la actualización de mi respuesta, con esto debe funcionar sin problema.

Comment: ya lo cambie hermano, pero sigue marcando el mismo error, actualize mi pregunta con las modificaciones que me sugeriste, crees que este haciendo algo mal aun :c

Comment: Elimina las variables de las vistas, tampoco son necesarias,elimina esta linea : Button btnListar, btnBuscar, btnRegistrar;

Comment: ya la elimine hermano, pero el erro sigue :c

Comment: ufff tambien tienes este import: import static com.example.myapplication.R.id.btnBusqueda; debería ser solo : import static com.example.myapplication.R;

Comment: lo aplique pero la librería me error en R. ya borre ambas librerias, pero el erro persiste y sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145774/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-el-chido).

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que declarar constantes de tus IDs a nivel de clase ya que desde View no puedes acceder a ellas.

Por ejemplo, podrías hacer lo siguiente

```
final int ID_BTN_LISTAR = R.id.Listado
```

Y esas constantes las usas en tu switch Case.

Espero te haya servido

Comment: muchas gracias, ya lo modifque pero me sigue marcando error,sabrias si lo estoy implementando mal?. 
   final int ID_BTN_LISTAR = R.id.btnListado;
    final int ID_BTN_BUSCAR = R.id.btnBusqueda;
    final int ID_BTN_REGISTRAR = R.id.btnRegistrar;.